# Using the join method with an object of arrays to separate with a comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object made up of an array which contains several objects. I am trying to use the join method but of course, I realised this is only available on arrays unless converted otherwise?

I want to separate the objects I need with a comma/pipe. The outcome should be as follows:

**DISOVER | EXPERIENCE | 195 LUXURY**

but need some guidance on how to achieve this since I'm getting the following error:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: data.slideHeading1.join is not a
>   function"

Is there an alternative way to do this? Please see my code below:

```js
var imgObj = {
  "slideData": [{
    "slideHeading1": "DISCOVER",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "EXPERIENCE",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "195 LUXURY",
  }]
};

imgObj.slideData.forEach(function(data, idx) {
  var heading1 = data.slideHeading1.join('|');
  var heading2 = data.slideHeading2.join('|');
  var heading3 = data.slideHeading3.join('|');

  $('.slideTitle .heading-1').append(heading1);
  $('.slideTitle .heading-2').append(heading2);
  $('.slideTitle .heading-3').append(heading3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="slideTitle">
  <span class="heading-1"></span>
  <span class="heading-2"></span>
  <span class="heading-3"></span>
</h2>
```

**Edit: Please see the following code which adds more objects to the array:** Also - I am using a text rotator which explains why the text is separated by a pipe.

Outcome should be:

```
<span class="heading-1">DISCOVER | EXPERIENCE | 195 LUXURY</span>
<span class="heading-2">MORE | IT ALL | SUPERJETS</span>
<span class="heading-3">FUEL | | TODAY</span>
```

Code example:

```js
var imgObj = {
  "slideData": [{
    "slideHeading1": "DISCOVER",
    "slideHeading2": "MORE",
    "slideHeading3": "FUEL",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "EXPERIENCE",
    "slideHeading2": "IT ALL",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "195 LUXURY",
    "slideHeading2": "SUPERJETS",
    "slideHeading3": "TODAY",
  }]
};

var heading1 = [];
imgObj.slideData.forEach(function(data, idx) {
  if (idx < imgObj.slideData.length - 1)
    heading1[idx] = data.slideHeading1 + ' | ';
  else // skip if the item is the last item
    heading1[idx] = data.slideHeading1;
});
document.querySelectorAll('span[class^=heading-]').forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.textContent = heading1[i]
});

$(".slideTitle span").Morphext({
  animation: "fadeInLeft",
  separator: "|",
  speed: 4000,
  complete: function() {
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Morphext/2.4.4/morphext.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Morphext/2.4.4/morphext.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="slideTitle">
  <span class="heading-1"></span>
  <span class="heading-2"></span>
  <span class="heading-3"></span>
</h2>
```

Comment: What output are you trying to get?

Comment: `data.slideHeadingX` return string, what you want to join here ??

Comment: You can just do `var heading1 = data.slideHeading1 + " | ";`
Will give you "DISCOVER | "

Comment: A join is to join values in an array together to form a string with a delimiter, you can't join on a string.

Comment: @dahliacreative The reason why I don't want to use the plus operator is because it will always add the the pipe at the end, the join method doesn't add it on the end.

Comment: @nixkuroi - just updated my question with the output desired, should be a pipe between each string, apart from the last, just like the join method achieves

Comment: ok well you could just make an array out of your headings then use join, if you have control over your data than just add a headings array?

Comment: @dahliacreative - yes good idea, however i've moved away from this because i have tonnes of other data linked inside one big object

Comment: yeah you can still keep your slides in an object but then inside each slide just have a key called headings, and make it an array. I think it's a much neater approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174886/discussion-between-zxynz-and-dahliacreative).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `data.slideHeading1` is not an array and `join()` is a method implemented on array.

I think you want to separate all items by pipe (`|`). If so, just add that character to the end of the text. Then loop through all the span element to fill with the text from the previously generated array. Something like the following:

```js
var imgObj = {
  "slideData": [{
    "slideHeading1": "DISCOVER",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "EXPERIENCE",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "195 LUXURY",
  }]
};

var heading1 = [];
imgObj.slideData.forEach(function(data, idx) {
  if(idx < imgObj.slideData.length - 1)
    heading1[idx] = data.slideHeading1 + ' | ';
  else // skip if the item is the last item
     heading1[idx] = data.slideHeading1;
});
document.querySelectorAll('span[class^=heading-]').forEach(function(el, i){
  el.textContent = heading1[i]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="slideTitle">
  <span class="heading-1"></span>
  <span class="heading-2"></span>
  <span class="heading-3"></span>
</h2>
```

**Please Note:** Since it is little bit confusing between the code you have approched and the text about what you are asking:

> I want to separate the objects I need with a comma

Simply replace

```
heading1[idx] = data.slideHeading1 + ' | ';
```

With

```
heading1[idx] = data.slideHeading1 + ', ';
```

Comment: apologies, I have corrected the question to be more clear on what I am asking. In essence, any sort of separator (comma, pipe etc) would be ok - I just need to understand the logic behind achieving the result

Comment: @zxynz, the logic is pretty simple which I have already explained in the answer....it would be nice if you mention any specific of which you are struggling to understand.

Comment: thanks - i have added an additional code block which has the exact library which I am using (text rotator). This will help explain what exactly my issue is.

Comment: @zxynz, now the question is a whole new one which is using a new library `morphext` and I know nothing about it.....hope you understand.

Comment: yes that's fine. But it is the very similar to your first answer I think. All that I need to do now is to append the first index in each object to heading-1, then each object in second index to heading-2 and same for the third. They will be separated with a pipe like you did

Answer (score 0):

Error you are getting because `data.slideHeading1` is not array but actual string value

Also Change `pipe(|)` to `comma(,)`

> > I want to separate the objects I need with a comma

**Just Change**

```
imgObj.slideData.forEach(function(data, idx) {
  var heading1 = data.slideHeading1.join('|');
  var heading2 = data.slideHeading2.join('|');
  var heading3 = data.slideHeading3.join('|');

  $('.slideTitle .heading-1').append(heading1);
  $('.slideTitle .heading-2').append(heading2);
  $('.slideTitle .heading-3').append(heading3);
});
```

**to this**

```
 imgObj.slideData.forEach(function(data, idx) {  
    var seperator = (idx==imgObj.slideData.length-1)? "":",";
                $('.slideTitle .heading-'+( idx+1)).append(data.slideHeading1 + seperator);
            });
```

```js
var imgObj = {
  "slideData": [{
    "slideHeading1": "DISCOVER",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "EXPERIENCE",
  }, {
    "slideHeading1": "195 LUXURY",
  }]
};

 
imgObj.slideData.forEach(function(data, idx) {  
var seperator = (idx==imgObj.slideData.length-1)? "":",";
            $('.slideTitle .heading-'+( idx+1)).append(data.slideHeading1 + seperator);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="slideTitle">
  <span class="heading-1"></span>
  <span class="heading-2"></span>
  <span class="heading-3"></span>
</h2>
```